# JSON code for my radio station website?

Tags: php, javascript, json, apache

This is part of my radio station website's PHP coding:
http://pastebin.com/D1TUMNSc

I've got the PHP to work; but getting the JSON to work is a problem, I'm not sure how to do it with the variables I've got...

Currently the schedule page shows as blank, since I'm not sure what to do.

The Javascript is here: http://pastebin.com/P1ydnVCK

Basically, I'm having trouble trying to create a JSON to fit within the variables of the Javascript, it's new to me, this area of programming...

What would you suggest?

I've had a look around the net at JSON resources but am not quite sure what to do for this one!

Comment: Welcome to SO! That's a lot of code. You will be much better off isolating a detailed problem, and posting the part relevant to that problem here. It's not clear from your question what exactly you are trying to achieve. Feel free to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON code for radio station website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542280/json-code-for-radio-station-website)

Comment: vote to close the other one since this has more activity

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look so this may not be everything you need, but....  You need to do something like this....

```
$json->schedule = array();

// Loop Here

    $show = array(
        'longname' => 'xxxxx',
        'description' => 'xxxxxx',
        'weblink' => 'http://xxxx.com',
        'showimage' => 'xxxx',
        'startminutes' => '0000000',
        'endminutes' => '000000',
    );

    // End Loop

    $json->schedule[] = $show;

    echo json_encode($json);
```

In your javascript anything prefixed with _s needs to be a variable... Ex: this._s.longname